# adding values from list item and checboxes

Tags: jquery, html, class, checkbox

Try to add value from checkboxes and item list to make a price calculator. where client select the type of service they want from item list or checkboxes , and price calculator give the quote for price.

```
$(".option").click(function() {
var total = 0;
$(".option:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
alert(total);
});


<table width="98%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="Summary Here">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Basic</th>
        <th>Requirements</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="light">
        <td height="31">Number of Pages</td>
        <td><select class="option">
          <option value="50">1</option>
          <option value="100">2</option>
          <option value="200">3</option>
          <option value="250">4</option>
          <option value="400">5-10</option>
          <option value="800">11-20</option>
          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
        </select></td>            
      </tr>
      <tr class="dark">
        <td>Domain Registration</td>
        <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="10" />Yes</td>
        </tr>
      <tr class="light">
        <td>Website Hosting</td>
        <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="60" />Yes</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="dark">
       <th>Options Extras</th>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
      <tr class="light">

        <td>Image Gallery Page</td>
        <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="100" />Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dark">
       <td>Videos</td>
       <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="60" />Yes</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="light">          
        <td>Membership System</td>
        <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="100" />Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dark">
       <td>Forum</td>
       <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="300" />Yes</td>
       <tr class="light">          
        <td>Image Creation</td>
        <td><select class="option">
          <option value="50">5-10</option>
          <option value="100">11-20</option>
          <option value="200">21-30</option>
          <option value="250">31-40</option>
          <option value="400">41-50</option>
          <option value="800">51-100</option>
          <option value="0" selected="selected">0</option>
        </select></td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dark">
       <td>Standard Mobile Website</td>
       <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="300" />Yes</td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="light">          
        <td>Site or Product Search</td>
        <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="60" />Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="dark">
       <td>File Uploads</td>
       <td><input class="option" type="checkbox" value="90" />Yes</td>
       </tr>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th><div id="total">£0</div></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You've tagged everything but you left out the jQuery tag..

Comment: What problem are you having exactly?

Comment: @Mr.Alien is this is on the top of the html. $(".option").click(function() {
var total = 0;
$(".option:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
});
alert(total);
});

Comment: @webdevelopersana I said the **TAG** and not the code, adding a tag will help you get answers from jQuery programmers, I added it anyways

Comment: @Mr.Alien you what do you mean by jQuery tag, can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://s11.postimage.org/6knfkfqyb/Untitled.jpg

Comment: @Mr.Alien you mean <script></script> tag

Comment: @webdevelopersana no dude, just see the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, put a link to the jquery script in your header, above your other script tag:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then use the .change() function in jquery, then add up all option:selected and input.option:checked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".option").change(function() {
      var total = 0;
      $(".option option:selected, input.option:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
      });
      $("#total").text("£" + total);
    });
  });
</script>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/vZwFx/

If you want your "total" div to be updated instead of an alert popping up, simply replace the alert call with `$("#total").text("£" + total);`

Comment: the demo link is what i exactly want, i have changed my code as mentioned above the "total" div is not displaying any result.<script>

$(".option").change(function() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".option option:selected, input.option:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
  });
  $("#total").text("£" + total);
});
</script>

Comment: If you want to use jquery, you need to include the jquery script on your page before you use it. See my updated answer.

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"
     type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".option").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".option option:selected, input.option:checked")
    .each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });
    $("#total").text("£" + total);
     });
     </script>
    </head>   still not displaying value

Comment: Copy and paste the code in my answer into your site - it will work.

Comment: I'm looking at the source of the site you linked above, and the script tag to include jquery is still not there.

Comment: aaron, i have added that jQuery script on header, yes i know its not visible at the source of the site my linked above i don't know why

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Wrap your code in a document.ready function. This makes sure that the page has fully loaded before trying to bind jquery actions. See my updated answer.

Comment: (http://sanainfotech.co.uk/services.html) check it out, it works now, thank you all